# What is the difference between Phaser.BitmapData ctx and context?

Tags: phaser-framework, pixi.js

Currently in Phaser.BitmapData class instance there are 2 properties (ctx and context) which are instances of CanvasRenderingContext2D when used lead to the same result of something been drawn on the new BitmapData. What is the difference between context and ctx and when each of them is supposed to be used?

Example:

```
var bmp = this.game.add.bitmapData(530, 200);
bmp.context.rect(0, 0, 530, 200);
bmp.context.fillStyle = '#FF0000';
bmp.context.fill();
```

VS

```
var bmp = this.game.add.bitmapData(530, 200);
bmp.ctx.rect(0, 0, 530, 200);
bmp.ctx.fillStyle = '#FF0000';
bmp.ctx.fill();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://phaser.io/docs/2.6.2/Phaser.BitmapData.html#context) it's the same. And if you look at [the source code](https://github.com/photonstorm/phaser/blob/v2.6.2/src/gameobjects/BitmapData.js#L60) you can see that `ctx` is just a reference to `context` so it's in fact the exact same thing.

Using the conventional name `ctx` as variable for the `context` is very common and also shorter to type, so that's probably the reasoning behind it.

Comment: You are probably correct. Still it bugs me in a strange way :) to have 2 absolutely same properties pointing to the same CanvasRenderingContext2D.